# Probability in a Restaurant

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In a revolving restaurant, there are four round tables each with three seats. How many different ways can $12$ people sit in this restaurant?

This is what I think the answer is:

$$\binom{12}{4} \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \binom43$$

Is this right?

Comment: $\frac{1}{3}\binom{4}{3}$ cannot be right. It is not even an integer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas the edit makes it easier to read.  The $\frac{1}{3}$ cancels with an earlier term and the proposed answer is indeed an integer (though much smaller than it probably should be).

Comment: I did not see that part (small display, and largish type, so I only see part of a page. The edit helps a lot, the old formula was broken between two lines).

Comment: What is the definition of a "revolving restaurant" and "different seatings" in such a restaurant?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $(abc)(def)(ghi)(jkl)$ is considered the same result as $(def)(ghi)(jkl)(abc)$ (i.e. rotations *of* tables is irrelevant) and $(bca)(def)(igh)(klj)$ (i.e. rotations *within* tables is irrelevant), but is considered different from $(bac)(def)(ghi)(jkl)$ (mirrors of tables considered different) and is considered different from $(def)(abc)(ghi)(jkl)$ (tables must remain in same order).

First, with the tables stopped still, assign each person to a table.  There are $\frac{12!}{3!3!3!3!}$ ways of doing that.

For each table, arbitrarily select one person to be special (by height or whiteness of teeth or name, it doesn't matter) and choose which of the two other people at the table sits on his/her left.

Finally, start the tables rotating and "forget" which table was situated in the north at the beginning (divide by 4)

The total number of ways then is $\frac{12!}{3!3!3!3!}\cdot 2^4\cdot \frac{1}{4}$

---

An equivalent solution relying more heavily on "dividing by symmetry"

Arrange everyone in a line: $12!$ number of ways to do this

The first three people in the line send to the first table and have them seat in the chairs in clockwise order as they had appeared in line starting from the north.  Do so similarly for the next group of three and the next group of three, etc...

"Forget" who was sat at the north on each table (divide by $3$ once for each table)

"Forget" which table was at the north to begin with once the restaurant starts spinning (divide by $4$)

For a total of $12!\cdot\frac{1}{3^4}\cdot \frac{1}{4}$ for the same answer as before.

Answer (score 0):

Let A(x) = 1 + x + x^2/2 + 2 x^3/3! + 6 x^4/4! and B(x) = x + x^2/2 + 2 x^3/3!
We want the coefficient of x^12/12! in A(B(x)) which is 1478400.  As an added bonus we know the number of ways to seat 0,1,2,...,12 people is: 1, 1, 2, 7, 29, 150, 820, 4130, 19670, 80080, 285600, 739200, 1478400.

Comment: Please use LaTeX (MathJax) to format your answer.